# SQL Azure Automated Backups doesn't work

Tags: azure, database-administration

I configured automated export of my SQL azure db, but backups are not created.
Also, I'am resieved this mail.

> Automated SQL Export failed for [servername]:[dbname] at 25.09.2013
>   23:06:45. The temporary database copy was made, but this copy could
>   not be exported to the .bacpac file in storage.
>
> NOTES: We recommend checking that the storage account is available,
>   and that you can perform a manual export to that account. We will
>   attempt to export again at the next scheduled time

I tryed to export db manualy in this storage accaunt — it was created without problems.

Comment: I'm also seeing these issues. Happens maybe once a week (with daily backups) and they seem to be transient since during other days the backups succeed.